# Why is identifierstyle used for lstlisting with no language?

Tags: color, listings, lstlisting, syntax-highlighting

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    identifierstyle=\color{red},
}
\lstnewenvironment{algol}{\lstset{language=algol}}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
foo
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{algol}
int foo
\end{algol}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Why is the first `lstlisting` example rendered with `identifierstyle` (red color)? What language's syntax highlighting was selected to do this rendering?

Here is a further minimal example that reproduces this issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    identifierstyle=\color{red},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
foo
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This produces the string "foo" in red color just like before. Why does this happen even if no language syntax is enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`listings` splits the input text into several token classes, depending on the current catcode regime set for the listing. The default rules for parsing identifiers is: a single letter followed by a sequence of letters or digits. Letters by default are `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z`, `@`, `$` and `_`; digits are `0`-`9`. Here's an example that demonstrates that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    identifierstyle=\color{red}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
foo
foo123
foo@bar__123
123$foo
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Each identifier is set using the current `identifiersstyle`. Any other character will stop the current identifier parsing and set the rest of the text in basic style until another identifier is found (or other special syntax elements like delimited environments etc.).

On top of this identifier parsing mechanism you can define special identifiers, e.g. keywords, for which you can also give an extra style, or change catcodes to make more/less letters being part of identifiers (cf. `alsoletter`, `alsoother` etc.).